# PHP glob function to match directories but not files

Tags: php, glob

I am trying to use the PHP function `glob()` to match **directories, not files**. I can get it to match all folders using `glob('*')`, but that matches files also. I can match all files using `glob(*.*)`, but that's not what I want.

Is there a way to *subtract* perameters from the `glob()` matching system, or should I use `preg_match()` to limit the results?

Comment: Look into [DirectoryIterator](http://php.net/manual/en/class.directoryiterator.php)

Comment: Did you even read the docs?

Comment: @Petah Yes, I did. I overlooked the key part, as I said in my comment to the answer below.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to the [manual](http://php.net/manual/en/function.glob.php):

> GLOB_ONLYDIR - Return only directory entries which match the pattern

So that would be:

```
glob('*', GLOB_ONLYDIR)
```